# shiro web step by step example not work,stormpath is moved

Tags: web, shiro, sample

[Shiro web example](http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html)
I follow this, but in step 2, the [stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) is moved to another site [okta](https://developer.okta.com/), so I don't know what shall I do.
There is an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load credentials from any provider in the chain.
```

So I wrote a reamls by myself.

```
public class CustomSecurityRealm extends JdbcRealm{

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        char[] psw = upToken.getPassword();
        String username = upToken.getUsername();
        return  new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, psw, getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DruidDataSource ds=new DruidDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=TRUE");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");
        dataSource=ds;
    }
}
```

And in shiro.ini I change `securityManager.realm = $stormpathRealm` to `securityManager.realm = realm.CustomSecurityRealm`
But exception is the same. Or sometimes no error when I delete it from tomcat and add again, but home page is not found --404.
I hate this, I just want to see how to use shiro in web project,why it is so hard?
I have no jndi, so I didn't copy from this [example](https://mehmetceliksoy.wordpress.com/2015/06/28/shiro-jdbc-realm/), I just want to make things simple. How can I run the web sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the examples in https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples

We will get that tutorial updated too.